# Split dataframe into multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am learning pandas for a new project and I am relatively new and seeking help. I have the following dataframe.

The DateTime range from “**2020-03-27 00:10:02**” to **2020-03-27 23:50:01** repeats 18 times across the dataframe capturing different types of data within this timeline.

I would like to split this dataframe into different dataframes each one having its own data related to the range “**2020-03-27 00:10:02**” to **2020-03-27 23:50:01**.

When I try:

`df [(df["Date"] > '2020-03-27 00:10:00') & (df ["Date"] < '2020-03-27 23:55:00')]`,

it selects the almost the entire dataframe across all the repetitive ranges.

Any suggestions? Dataframe attached as an image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sz80I.png)

Adding further information that the range repeats like below. (Although the length of the range is not important).

I would like to segregate each range of "12:00:01 AM" to "11:50:01 PM" into a dataframe each.

Row1    : 12:00:01 AM
Row3588 : 11:50:01 PM

Row3589 : 12:00:01 AM
Row3876 : 11:50:01 PM

Row3877 : 12:00:01 AM
Row4020 : 11:50:01 PM

Row4021  : 12:00:01 AM
Row4452  : 11:50:01 PM

Comment: Hi, there's not enough here to work with.  You will need to give example data (including column names), and an example of the output you want to get.

Comment: Hey, I added new information. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Do let me know if you need more information. I will try to be more detailed. Appreciate your help.

Comment: IT is not clear what you want to do

Comment: The range "12:00:01 AM" to "11:50:01 PM" repeats multiple times capturing unique data. I Need to segregate the original dataframe into multiple dataframes with each dataframe having the data belonging to each range. You can consider a linux based SAR report file in ASCII format

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to **make sure there is no duplicate and there are 18 different type of data for each DateTime index.**

For example, it seems that there is only one row corresponding to 2020-03-27 23:50:01. At this point, you cannot really separate the dataframe yet since the data is not stored in a consistent format. If you can figure out ways to have 18 data types for each time, then you could try

```
df_type1 = df.loc[[i for i in range(9820) if i % 18 ==0],:]
df_type2 = ...
```

Comment: Hi, There is no duplicate data. Each time range has different information. I just want to segregate the data belonging to each range into a different dataframe.

Comment: Ok, there might be no duplicate. But, there is only one row with 2020-03-27 23:50:01 for instance even though you say there are 18 different types for each DateTime index. You should account for these inconsistencies in data. Or, do you have a column that specifies what is the type of data for each row?